# org.neo4j.kernel.guard.GuardTimeoutException: timeout occured (overtime=2)

Tags: neo4j

neo4j-server.properties

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads=1000
```

neo4j.properties

```
execution_guard_enabled=true
```

my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    try (Transaction tx = service.beginTx();) {
       // do somthing
        tx.success();
        tx.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw ex;
      }

}
```

while  run about 3 hours,thows GuardTimeoutException as the following:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.guard.GuardTimeoutException: timeout occured (overtime=2)
at org.neo4j.kernel.guard.Guard$Timeout.check(Guard.java:128)
at org.neo4j.kernel.guard.Guard.check(Guard.java:42)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.GuardingStatementOperations.nodeGetRelationships(GuardingStatementOperations.java:357)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeGetRelationships(OperationsFacade.java:352)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy$2.iterator(NodeProxy.java:194)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy$2.iterator(NodeProxy.java:186)
at com.xxx.neo4j.plugin.knitter.service.KnitterService.setInvestFrom(KnitterService.java:389)
```

Comment: Please add your `org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime` value (stored in neo4j-server.properties)

Comment: what is the question? and `tx.close()` *ALWAYS* needs to be in a `finally` block.

Comment: sorry, I copy the wrong config,org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime=10000,not the org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads=1000

Comment: the question is why GuardTimeoutException occus